# Issue with setting colors in code using unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to unity and I am having issues with setting Colors of GameObjects in code uniquely. I have a class called circle and in that class it has a variable Color. There is a list of this class constructed with the line: `public List<circle> circleList = new List<circle>();`
This list is linked to another list of gameobjects, called cloneList. In order to change the color of each gameobject I use the following code:

```
        for (int a = 0; a < circleList.Count; ++a)
        {
            Material newMaterial = tempMaterial;
            newMaterial.SetColor("_Color", circleList[a].color);
            cloneList[a].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = newMaterial;
        }
```

However, instead of updating each gameobject's color individually, it changes all of them at the same time, specifically to the last element in the list's color. I believe this behaviour has something to do with the fact that I use pointers, but I am too inexperienced to figure out exactly where the mistake occurs. Here is the full code for the minimum reproducible example, including adding some data in the two lists to show the point. (Temp Material being the default material in unity, and one and two being any gameObjects sufficiently spaced apart to be able to see changes in color)

```
    public class circle
    {
        public Color color;
    }
    public List<GameObject> cloneList;
    public List<circle> circleList = new List<circle>();
    public Material tempMaterial;
    public GameObject one, two;
    void Update()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < circleList.Count; ++a)
        {
            Material newMaterial = tempMaterial;
            newMaterial.SetColor("_Color", circleList[a].color);
            cloneList[a].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = newMaterial;
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        circleList.Capacity = 2;
        cloneList.Capacity = 2;
        circle tempCircleOne = new circle();
        tempCircleOne.color = new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        circle tempCircleTwo = new circle();
        tempCircleTwo.color = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        circleList.Add(tempCircleOne);
        circleList.Add(tempCircleTwo);
        cloneList.Add(one);
        cloneList.Add(two);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Material newMaterial = tempMaterial;
```

In this part you're creating a new material by referencing to the `tempMaterial`. So when you change color, you're actually changing color of `tempMaterial` and as a result of that all `newMaterial` change color too.

Instead of that, you can do

`Material newMaterial = new Material(tempMaterial);`

You can look them up in the links below

[Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html)

[Material Constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-ctor.html)